# How can I find out which proxy server is used in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

How can I find out which proxy server is used in Ubuntu from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output the proxy of the current session:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

Answer (score 3):

Since environment variable pointing to proxy may be case sensitive and exist not only for HTTP but HTTPS and FTP protocols, and there's as well the way to avoid usage of proxy server for some addresses or server names with NO_PROXY variable I believe the proper command should be a bit more complex:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

which will produce an output like

```
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local,*.domain.com,192.168.0.0/16
FTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.6:3128
https_proxy=http://192.168.1.6:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.6:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.6:3128
http_proxy=http://192.168.1.6:3128
```